# Android wrong view measurement: TextView displays entire string in preview but only displays first character in phone/emulator

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout, textview

**Scenario:**

- I am showing a Fragment inside my MainActivity for Sign in.
- That Fragment has 3 TextViews.
- In Android Studio preview, the TextViews display their texts correcly;
- In phones/emulators, the TextViews only display the first letter of their texts.

**Here are the code and screenshots:**

*1 - Everything looks fine in my preview in Android Studio when i use:*

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

or

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

[image: Layout preview in Android Studio (variable width)]

*2 - However, when I run the app, the phone/emulator displays the TextViews only with the first letter of the string:*

[image: Same layout in phone/emulator displays only first letters in TextViews with variable width (wrap_content or match_parent)]

*3 - If I set the width with any fixed size like:*

```
android:layout_width="200dp"
```

the preview looks like this:

[image: Layout preview in Android Studio (fixed width)]

*4 - When I run the app, the TextViews display the text correctly:*

[image: Same layout in phone/emulator displays the entire string in TextViews with fixed width (200dp)]

**Additional information:**

- I am using the red border background to highlight the edges of the TextViews and they look right in both scenarios.

**Can anybody point out what am I doing wrong? Why the phone/emulator is displaying only the first letters of the strings when the width is variable?**

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_red_corners"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_sign_in_picture"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_red_corners"
        android:contentDescription="@string/user_picture"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_people"
        android:tint="@color/gray" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_red_corners"
        android:text="@string/hi"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_red_corners"
        android:text="@string/sign_in_statement" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_red_corners"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The background drawable for the red borders:

bg_red_corners.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/red" />
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

*I am chaging the background of the LinearLayout to make the layouts more visual:*

My preview in Android Studio:

[image: Preview on Android Studio with gray background]

The result on the phone/emulator:

[image: Phone/emulator with gray background]

Now I will change the height of the LinearLayout from

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Android Studio preview:

[image: Android Studio preview with LinearLayout height="match_parent"]

The result in the phone/emulator:

[image: Phone/emulator with LinearLayout height="match_parent"]

**Now it becomes more weird:**

I will change the height of the second TextView from

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

[image: Android Studio preview with second TextView height="match_parent"]

The phone/emulator will display the entire string, but in 1 column:

[image: Phone/emulator when second TextView has height="match_parent"]

SignInFragment.java

```
public class SignInFragment
        extends
        BaseFragment {


    private static volatile SignInFragment INSTANCE;

    /**
     * SignInFragment is SINGLETON
     * @return instance of SignInFragment
     */
    public static SignInFragment getInstance() {
        Timber.d("getInstance: ");
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (SignInFragment.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = new SignInFragment();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }


    private SignInFragment() {
        Timber.d("SignInFragment: ");
    }

    private MainActivityControlInterface mainActivityControlInterface;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        Timber.d("onAttach: ");
        super.onAttach(context);
        mainActivityControlInterface = (MainActivityControlInterface) context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Timber.d("onCreateView: ");
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        setupUi();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Timber.d("onPrepareOptionsMenu: ");
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void setupUi() {
        Timber.d("setupUi: ");
    }


}
```

BaseFragment.java:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    public static String TAG = "BaseFragment";

    MyApplication mApplication;
    BaseActivity mBaseActivity;
    Context mContext;
    MainActivityControlInterface mainActivityControlInterface;
    long startTime;
    long loadTime;

    @Inject
    public ViewModelDi viewModelDi;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mApplication = (MyApplication)context.getApplicationContext();
        mApplication.getDiComponent().inject(this);
        mainActivityControlInterface = (MainActivityControlInterface) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mBaseActivity = (BaseActivity) getActivity();
        mContext = mBaseActivity.getContext();
    }


    public void hideKeyboard() {
        Util.hideKeyboard(mBaseActivity);
    }


    public String getTAG() {
        return TAG;
    }

    public void setTAG(String TAG) {
        this.TAG = TAG;
    }


}
```

Thank you!

Comment: try to remove background from TextView's, maybe background is causing TextView to measuring wrong. Do you maybe changing TextViews somehow from fragment? Or do you have any other strings.xml files for different languages?

Comment: Hi @mmmatey, thanks for commenting. I already tried to remove the background but I still face the issue. The Fragment only shows the layout, it means that I am not binding the TextViews in my Fragment, so the Fragment does not know about the them. Lastly, I am using different string.xml files for different languages, however, all files have the same string (they are not translated yet).

Comment: A. R. Goncalve, did you try to rebuild you project, I guess you did right, if not tried that first. What's the white layout in which you are showing those TextView-s?

Comment: @mmmatey unfortunately I do not have reputation enough to edit the question, so I cannot upload more images nor code. The white layout in which I am showing the TextViews is the LinearLayout that I posted in the question. Notice that all layouts have the red borders to show their edges. I tried to clean/rebuild and even delete the .build folder, however, nothing has taken effect. All layouts in my hierarchy have width="match_parent". This behavior is really weird, since I did this kind of layout many times before and they always worked right.

Comment: hi @mmmatey I was able to edit the question and I put more information and I got another weird behavior when changing the height of the views.

Comment: It seems that one something is breaking you TextView width, what is base class for your fragment, can you maybe share also **SigInFragment**? Looks to me like parent class or something higher don't allow text to match width.

Comment: I added both SignInFragment and BaseFragment to the question. Thank you!

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97556/helping-out-android-user-with-textview-issue join me in this chat room to continue our discussion.

Comment: I guess you can't join chat, anyway tell me how you are adding your fragment SignInFragment to fragment manager of activity, also this code would be great to  see it - SignInFragmnet should not be a Singleton - this is first mistake - as far I can see from code. There are other ways, but first let's see how you are adding fragment to activity.

Comment: Also one more thing which can affect to all TextViews is Theme, or style, do you have defined and override any **style** in **style.xml** file or **theme.xml** files?